# Using calculus to find the maximum involving digamma function (in Latent Dirichlet Allocation).

Tags: calculus, optimization, machine-learning, digamma-function

I am having difficulty seeing how the authors (in Appendix A.3.2 under "Variational Dirichlet" of [this paper](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/irwin.king/_media/presentations/latent_dirichlet_allocation.pdf)) maximise the function $L$ with respect to $\gamma_i$ to derive a solution for $\gamma_i$.

$L_{[\gamma]}$ refers to only those parts of the function $L$ which contain $\gamma_i$:

$$L_{[\gamma]} = \sum^k_{i=1} (\Psi(\gamma_i) - \Psi(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j))(\alpha_i + \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) - \log \Gamma(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j) + \log \Gamma(\gamma_i)$$

Where $\Psi(\cdot)$ is the *digamma function* and $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the *gamma function*. They evaluate partial derivatives with respect to $\gamma_i$ to get the following:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \gamma_i} = \Psi'(\gamma_i) (\alpha_i + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) - \Psi'(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j) \displaystyle \sum^k_{j=1} (\alpha_j + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) $$

Where they have used the result that the derivative of $\log \Gamma(x)$ with respect to $x$ is $\Psi(x)$, and where $\Psi'(\cdot)$ is the 1st derivative of the digamma function. I have checked the above derivation, and it am satisfied with this.

**However, I am  now struggling to see how the authors go from the above line to derive a maximum in the following line.**

They then set this equal to 0, yielding a maximum with respect to $\gamma_i$:

$$\gamma_i = \alpha_i + \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni}$$

**My attempt (updated to correct algebraic error).**

The paper is well-known and is frequently cited in the machine learning community, so it's almost certainly due to something I'm missing rather than a typo or error.

Defining an index set $S = \{1, ..., k\}$, I separated the $i$th summand in the right-most summation from the rest of the summands to yield:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \gamma_i} = & \space \Psi'(\gamma_i) (\alpha_i + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) - \Psi'(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j) \displaystyle \sum^k_{j=1} (\alpha_j + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) \\
= & \space\Psi'(\gamma_i) (\alpha_i + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) - \Psi'(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j) (\alpha_i + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) \\
&- \Psi'(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j) \displaystyle \sum_{j \in S \backslash \{i\}} (\alpha_j + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) \\
= & \space (\alpha_i + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) \left( \Psi'(\gamma_i) - \Psi'(\textstyle \sum^K_{j=1} \gamma_j) \right) \\
&- \Psi'(\textstyle \sum^k_{j=1} \gamma_j) \displaystyle \sum_{j \in S \backslash \{i\}} (\alpha_j + \textstyle \sum^N_{n=1} \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) \\
= & \space 0
\end{align}$$

**Now setting this derivative equal to 0, the nature of the argument that the authors use to derive the maximum is currently obtuse to me.**

Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Further context.**

As context, the function $L$ is, in the language of the machine-learning and statistics community, an *evidence lower bound* (i.e. a bound on a marginal log-likelihood which is analytically intractable to compute), and its arguments consist of *model parameters* and *variational parameters*.

My query concerns maximising $L$ with respect to the variational parameter $\gamma_i$. The $\gamma_1, ... , \gamma_k$ are simply (variational) parameters of the *Dirichlet distribution*. Similarly, the $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k$ are (model) parameters of the Dirichlet distribution. The $\phi_{nj}$ are probabilities, so that $\sum^k_{j=1} \phi_{nj} = 1$ (they correspond to the probability of the $n$th word in a document being drawn from the $j$th latent topic).

The maximum derived is part of a two-stage iterative EM-like procedure (in the sense of Dempster et al.) where we maximise $L$ with respect to the variational parameters $\gamma_i$ with model parameters $\alpha_i$ held fixed, followed by maximising $L$ with respect to model parameters $\alpha_i$, with the variational parameters $\gamma_i$ held fixed.